# Symfony services.yaml binding arguments from vendor Bundle

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have prepared my CMS Bundle which is stored in my private repository and added via Composer to `vendor` directory.

Why binding scalar argumends from `@MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yaml` doesn't work? I have to copy paste them into app `config/services.yaml`.

Please see services.yaml in my vendor bundle:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false
    bind:
      $suffix: '%env(SUFFIX)%'
      $loadBlocks: '%mmcms.load_blocks%'
```

and app/config/services/yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true

        bind:
            $sender: Custom name
            Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $appCrash: "@monolog.logger.appcrash"
```

When I use `$suffix` in vendor bundle services it works but if I want to autowire it in constructor of my App service it doesn't work.

A get an error:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Mailer\MailerHelper": argument "$suffix" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.
```

I know that this binding, defaults are only for this particular services file, so the scope is for the bundle.

Is there a possibility to handle it somehow in order not to copy paste the bind configuration?

Comment: Consider updating your question showing the relevant portions of your two service files.  There is no reason why binding a parameter defined in a bundle to a value in your app will not work.  Possibly a typo.  Here is an [example](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-local-service-binding).

Comment: @Cerad I have added code example. As shown in docs you have provider a link for, they say it is local binding that is why maybe it won't work? SO local for vendor bundle won't work in app?

Comment: Of course it does not.  Anything under _defaults only applies to services defined within the particular services.yaml file.

Comment: Exactly, so is there a nice way to fix this instead of repeating the code?

Comment: The use of autowire in bundles is discouraged so in that sense, there is nothing to fix.  Plus, global binding does not seem to be a very good idea.  Imagine loading a bundle and having it bind to some common name.  Could get confusing.  But no, I can't think of a work around. Doubt if the binding info is available during a compiler pass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way!
If you made your CMS bundle as a vendor bundle just configure your service inside it and don’t rely on auto wiring for it. Place the services.yaml file inside ‘Resources/config/services.yaml’ then you need to load the configuration in your dependencyinjection file here is an [example](https://github.com/netbull/CoreBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/NetBullCoreExtension.php)

Comment: Thank you. I've probably not asked right question :) I am talking about binding parameters. Parameters are already loaded to the main App, but I want to bind scalar arguments so that they are available for Services constructor in App. Like: _defaults: bind: $myParameter: '%my_parameter%' which then will be available to inject in services constructor by $myParameter variable.